An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail
we are facing Fault Exception while Accessing Tridion Classic UI. we are able to access New Ui & Access management successfully.
We have identified Local Machine certificates are Expired. How to renewal Local machine certificate? it's depend with any tridion related script?
web.config:
<clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="TrustedPeople" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="xxxxxxxxxx" />
            <serviceCertificate>
              <defaultCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="TrustedPeople" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="xxxxxxxxxxx" />
            </serviceCertificate>

Error Details:
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail. ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: At least one security token in the message could not be validated. --- End of inner exception stack trace --- Server stack trace: at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory1.SecurityRequestChannel.ProcessReply(Message reply, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.DoOperation(SecuritySessionOperation operation, EndpointAddress target, Uri via, SecurityToken currentToken, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.GetTokenCore(TimeSpan timeout) at System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenProvider.GetToken(TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionClientSettings1.ClientSecuritySessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.LayeredChannel1.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation) at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message) Exception rethrown at [0]: at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ISessionAwareCoreService.GetCurrentUser() at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.SessionAwareCoreServiceClient.ImpersonateAndGetAccessToken(IPrincipal principal) at ActLike_ICoreServiceWrapper_acaf6c439a2042029317c9eb51ad9606.ImpersonateAndGetAccessToken(IPrincipal principal) at Tridion.Web.CMUtils.CMSession.get_CoreServiceClient() at Tridion.Web.CMUtils.CMSession.Authorize() at Tridion.Web.UI.Models.TCM54.Http.TcmAuthorizationModule.OnAuthorizeRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.HttpApplication.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

This error message doesn't say much (other than that an error occurred). Please check the Tridion Event Log.

Hi @RickPannekoek, Just updated New finding, can you please verify & confirm for same.
